# Invoke Helpform from extended data types [enum]

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a problem with Extended Data Types Enum with HelpForm, the form (HelpForm) doesn't open on action.

But if I use a string extended data type and set property HelpForm, the form is run on click ButtonImage (similar to extended data type `FileNameSave`).

Does AX 2009 support HelpForm in enum extended data types?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the extended data type property `FormHelp`. If this assumption is correct, then I was able to reproduce the issue on my AX 2009 system. Could you [edit] into your question some information about the business requirement why you want to change the standard lookup behavior of an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section [Controls that use Lookup Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa597861.aspx#Anchor_0) in the documentation does not list `ComboBox` controls (which are the controls used for extended data types based on an enum) as a control type that does support custom lookup forms. The documentation is for AX 2012, but I think in this case it also applies to AX 2009.